# Fragment shader not creating gradient like light in OpenGL GLSL

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, glsl, shader

I am trying to understand how to manipulate my renderings with shaders. I haven't changed the projection matrix of the scene but I draw a triangle with vertices = {-0.5, -0.5} {0.5, -0.5} {0, 0.5}. I then pass in a vec2 position of a "light" to the uniform of my fragment shader that i want to essentially shine onto my triangle from the top right of the triangle (lightPos = (0.5,0.5))

Here is a very bad drawing of where everything is located.

[image: Terrible image i made in paint]

and this is what I aim to have in my triangle (kind of.. it doesnt need to be white to blue it just needs to be brighter near the light and darker further away)

[image: Example image]

Here is the shader

```
#version 460 core

in vec3 oPos;
out vec4 fragColor;

uniform vec3 u_outputColor;
uniform vec2 u_lightPosition;

void main(){

float intensity =  1 / length(oPos.xy - u_lightPosition);
vec4 col = vec4(u_outputColor, 1.0f);
fragColor = col * intensity; 
}
```

Here is the basic code to compiling the shader(most of it is abstracted away so it is fairly simple)

```
/* Test data for shader program. */
program.init("passthrough.vert", "passthrough.frag");
program.setUniformVec3("u_outputColor", 0.3f, 0.3f, 0.8f);
program.setUniformVec2("u_lightPosition", 0.5f, 0.5f);



GLfloat vertices[9] = {-0.5f, -0.5, 0,    0,0.5f,0,    0.5, -0.5, 0};
```

Here is vertex shader:

```
#version 460 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
out vec3 oPos;

void main(){
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);
}
```

Every single test I have run to see why I can't get this to work seems to show me that if there is a slight color change it will change the entire triangle to a different shade. All tests show a triangle of ONE color across the entire thing; no gradient at all. I want the triangle to be a gradient that is brighter near the light and darker further from it. This is driving me crazy because I have been stuck on such a simple thing for 3 hours now and it just seems like any code I write modifies all 3 vertices at once as if they are in the exact same spot. I wrote the math out and I strongly feel as if this should work. Any help is very appreciated.

**EDIT**

The triangle after the solution fixed my issue:

[image]

Comment: Post your vertex shader, and an image showing your current output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for your vertex shader:

```
#version 460 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
out vec3 oPos;

void main(){
    oPos.xyz  = aPos.xyz; // ADD THIS LINE
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos.xyz, 1.0);
}
```

Your version never writes to `oPos`, so the fragment shader gets either a) a random value or, in your case b) `vec3(0,0,0)`. Since your color calculation is based  off of:

```
float intensity =  1 / length(oPos.xy - u_lightPosition);
```

This is basically the same as

```
float intensity =  1 / length(-1*u_lightPosition);
```

So the color only depends on the light position.

You can debug and verify this by setting your fragment color to `oPos`:

```
vec4 col = vec4(oPos.xy, oPos.z + 0.5, 1.0f);
```

If `oPos` was set correctly in the vertex shader, then this line in the fragment shader would show you an RGB ramp. If `oPos` is not set correctly, you'll see 50% blue.

**Always** check for errors and logs returned from OpenGL. It *should* have emitted a warning about this that would have sent you straight to the problem.

Also, I'm surprised that your entire triangle isn't being clipped since vertices have a `z` of `0`.

Comment: @Luke Glad to help. We all started somewhere. I've done worse things than this, and I'm a "professional." Sometimes, all it takes is an extra set of eyes to find the problem.